# Make function look-friendly like an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works:

```
$('.test').swipe({
    tap: function(){
        alert('testing');
    }
});

$('#hello').swipe({
    tap: function(){
        alert('hello world');
    }
});
```

I can *resume* it with:

```
function tap(obj, fn){
    $(obj).swipe({
        tap: fn
    });
};
```

Then, to use it I can do:

```
tap('.test', function(){
    alert('testing');
});

tap('#hello', function(){
    alert('hello world');
});
```

But I want it more look-friendly like an event:

```
$('.test').on('tap', function(){
    alert('testing');
});

$('#hello').on('tap', function(){
    alert('hello world');
});
```

How can I *resume* it that way?

Comment: You can create your own events, in pure javascript or in jquery. Look at this: https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/ || https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

Comment: And this is interesting too https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creacion_y_Activaci%C3%B3n_Eventos

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use the first notation though, to have a clear separation of widgets and widget events running on given DOM elements? (in this aspect, `swipe` widget should create `tap` event on the `$('.test')`, but notation will remain the same, I guess)

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile? If so, it looks like it has a tap event. Forgot to add the link. https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Comment: @eithedog. It is because I will use just `tap` with more frequency... the first method will always be possible :) .... @MarcosPérezGude I'm looking into.. thanks .... @t34t5 No, I'm not, and as I am using this `swipe` library I prefer just doing that instead adding another library

Comment: What are the new `hello` and `bye` elements? Do they have the `test` class?

Comment: @Blubberguy22 It was just to explain that I want an _alias (I don't know if that is the word)_ like the function `tap` I had done

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I'm pretty sure you would still do it the same way I had written in my answer (which I have updated).

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes What do you mean by "resume"?

Comment: I mean an way to simplify the code, but I want also to maintain friendly look

Answer (score 0):

[As Marcos Pérez Gude said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795207/make-function-look-friendly-like-an-event/34795328#comment57333786_34795207), you can create your own events. As you don't want to use the jQuery mobile library, you can make your own `tap` event. For example:

```
$('.test').on('tap', function(){
    alert('testing');
});

$('#hello').on('tap', function(){
    alert('hello world');
});

$('#bye').on('tap', function(){
    alert('leaving out');
});
```

And then to trigger the events:

```
$('.test').swipe({
    tap: function(){
        $(this).trigger('tap')
    }
});
$('#hello').swipe({
    tap: function(){
        $(this).trigger('tap')
    }
});

$('#bye').swipe({
    tap: function(){
        $(this).trigger('tap')
    }
});
```

Comment: My jquery hasn't `on.('swipe')`.. and I'm using `touchSwipe.js`, then if possible I want to avoid adding jQuery mobile library just because of that

Comment: I think the question is more about triggering functions (that were created by widgets) by firing events - in this aspect trigger of `tap` should run all the `$.fn[widget]tap` functions; at least that's how I'm reading it. I guess it all depends on what actually widget does - if it binds events, or not

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'm confused... I've edited my question.. can you show how it would be with my new test cases?

Comment: Can you add the `$('#hello')` event to your answer? Maybe I understand how it would be

Comment: You can see in my question, when I create `function tap()`.. I did it once and it is okay to run it two, three or more times.... I mean, there is no advantage in your way against my first method which I want to resume

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Then I guess I'm not understanding your question correctly.